# Cant add product to cart

Tags: addtocart, ee-1.14.3.0

When I try to add a product for first time,  using incognito tab and Full Page Cache, I get redirected to an empty cart.

Then, if I return the page and add the product again, or if I I select another product, I can add it. but not the first time.

My button code is this

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart form-key" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is generated by Full Page Cache,

My solution was install Letis FPC

https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/configure-lestifpc/#Download_LestiFPC